# C# Insert And Select in one string query

Tags: c#, mysql, select, insert

I use select query to read the values and then reinsert(Not update) them with some updates with the code below.
I am trying to run this query with insert and select the same time but is not working and I don't take any errors.

```
string docdetls = "Insert into DocDetls (DocStatus,  DocType, DocNo,SeqNo,ItemCode,Quantity,Price,Disc,DiscAmount,VAT,ExpDate)"+
                    "(SELECT 2 as DocStatus,  DocType, @newdocno as DocNo,SeqNo,ItemCode,Quantity,Price,Disc,DiscAmount,VAT,ExpDate FROM docdetls where  DocStatus=@stat and DocNo=@docno)";
MySqlCommand cmd4 = new MySqlCommand(docdetls, con);
cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("stat", "1");
cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("newdocno", DocNoTxtBox.Text);
cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("DocNo",no );
con.Open();
cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

If I run the same query on mysql workbench with some values is working.
Is this possible?How i can make this work?

UPDATE after the answer

```
       string docdetls = "Insert into DocDetls (DocStatus,  DocType, DocNo,SeqNo,ItemCode,Quantity,Price,Disc,DiscAmount,VAT,ExpDate)"+
                        "(SELECT 2 as DocStatus,  DocType, @newdocno as DocNo,SeqNo,ItemCode,Quantity,Price,Disc,DiscAmount,VAT,ExpDate FROM docdetls where  DocStatus=@stat and DocNo=@docno)";
                    MySqlCommand cmd4 = new MySqlCommand(docdetls, con);
                    cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("stat", "1");
                    //cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("newdocno", DocNoTxtBox.Text);
                    cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("DocNo",no );
                    cmd4.Parameters.Add("@newdocno", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = DocNoTxtBox.Text;
                    con.Open();
 cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
```

Still not working..

Comment: The question is about inserting **with** select. Not about insert **and** select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it with the code below

```
 string docdetls = "Insert into DocDetls (DocStatus,  DocType, DocNo,SeqNo,ItemCode,Quantity,Price,Disc,DiscAmount,VAT,ExpDate)"+
                        "(SELECT 2 as DocStatus,  DocType, @newdocno as DocNo,SeqNo,ItemCode,Quantity,Price,Disc,DiscAmount,VAT,ExpDate FROM docdetls where  DocStatus=@stat and DocNo=@docno)";
                    MySqlCommand cmd4 = new MySqlCommand(docdetls, con);
                    cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("stat", "1");
                    //cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("newdocno", DocNoTxtBox.Text);
                    cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("DocNo",no );
                    cmd4.Parameters.Add("@newdocno", MySqlDbType.Int16).Value = DocNoTxtBox.Text;
                    con.Open();
                    cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a few things;

You can't parameterize your column names. You can only parameterize your values. That's why `@newdocno as DocNo` should not work. If you want to take this column as an input, you really do some strong validation before you concatenate it in your string or use a white list.

For being more clear, you should define your parameter names in your command and your parameter collection identical. That means, if you have

```
where  DocStatus=@stat and DocNo=@docno
```

in your command, your parameter collection should be as;

```
cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stat", "1");
cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocNo",no );
```

As a best practice, don't use `AddWithValue` method. [It *might* generates unexpected and surprising results](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use [`.Add()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbparametercollection.add.aspx) to specify your parameter type and it's size instead.

And use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your database connections and commands automatically instead of calling `Close` methods manually.

Comment: And what about @newdocno? i need it.. Is there a way put it?

Comment: Is the only option white list? Can you show me an example with my code how to do white list?

Comment: @marios I mentioned it in my answer. You try to parameterize your column name which is not allowed. You should use string concatenation for your column but before you do it, you need to use _really_ strong validation before you put it in your sql or create a whitelist which it includes valid column names.

Comment: I dont need validation for this textbox because i generate the number from my code and put it there and i set enable=false..

Comment: Your answer didnt help me to solve my problem! I cant accept it